# Voltage transfer ratio of series RC network

Tags: control-system, transfer-function

I am trying to get the voltage transfer ratio Vout/Vin of this circuit. I tried taking a reference node and make a signal flow graph but it's not really matching my simulation. Can someone help me out?

[image]

Comment: Without a load, it would be "non-sense" ...

Comment: Vout/Vin = 1, for all frequencies > 0.

Comment: @Antonio51 I was wondering the same. So this RC network is basically between two nodes of different voltages. There's an IEEE paper where they've actually solved a similar problem. I can't seem to get the link but it's titled "Frequency domain analysis of fixed-on time with bottom detection control for buck converter". I tried this method but I still can't get satisfactory results

Comment: @Mattman944 how can you say so?

Comment: Load = infinite, voltage divider equation: infinite/(some_network + infinite). In real application, load must not be infinite.

Comment: @Mattman944 actually The circuit has two voltage sources. In the IEEE paper I mentioned, they've used the theory of superposition.

Comment: @Arshiya So then what is your question about: the circuit that you're showing, or the paper which you are only mentioning?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen It's about this circuit. The paper shows a similar circuit. I was giving a reference. Do you think If i add a load at the output end, it will make much more sense?

Comment: You can't guess at the load, the calculation will only be valid for the actual load. Can you show more of the circuit? Maybe Vout is some type of summing node.

Comment: The only thing you can do is to define an "impedance matrix" or any other "matrix" you want ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that can be done (is defining an Impedance matrix ...) or  varying the "Load" R3 at output as a parameter.

So, you can define a function Vout/Vin (load included !), but when Load R3 => infinity, it is a pass-all (as pointed out by @Mattman944), as can be seen in this simulation.

Note the very very "low" corner frequencies.

[image]